# Cant load vendors dependencies with composer for Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, composer-php

trying to install and run https://github.com/strimeapp which is based on Symfony 2.8

I first git cloned the code to my active localhost directory.
Then cd to it and composer install

Output of the command:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.47
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.46
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.45
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.44
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.43
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.42
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.41
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.40
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.39
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.36
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.34
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.33
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.32
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.31
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.30
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.29
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.27
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.26
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.25
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.24
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.23
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.22
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.21
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.20
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.18
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.16
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.15
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.1
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.0.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.18|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/intl v3.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.8.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/intl ^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/intl[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
```

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.5.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.6.*",
        "doctrine/annotations": "1.4.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.1",
        "symfony/intl": "^3.0",
        "xsolve-pl/xsolve-cookie-acknowledgement-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "~1.2",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^4.1",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "1.*",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.1",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^1.4",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.4",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.3",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "strimeapp/slackify": "0.*",
        "symfony/config": "^3.2",
        "google/apiclient": "2.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple times and followed different bug leads without success. It should be very straightforward. Using symfony/composer on other projects without problems. I dont understand where the conflict originates.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `symfony/symfony` package already includes the Intl component (which you try to install with the `symfony/intl` package). This is something Composer wrongly allowed in older versions and was fixed in Composer 1.7.3.

Do you really need the Intl component in version 3? If that's the case, you need to remove `symfony/symfony` first and require all the needed components explicitly if you cannot upgrade all Symfony packages to 3.

The same applies to other Symfony components.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I tried and use Composer v1.4.2 and all dependencies were succesfully resolved as they were originally listed in the .json